# Button got smaller when the background color is changed

Tags: android, button, background-color

I have a button whose background color I changed with this:   android:background="#C0C0C0" and on the emulator, the button is smaller than it was when I didn't have a background color.  Is that normal?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal for Button, because the default background image is a nine-patch that defines padding.  The padding is added to the size of the text, so when you set the button to just a color, the padding is removed and your button gets smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two to your button element:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:padding="0dp"
```